# how can I call a function when time expire

Tags: php, users, account

I have this function but the function name is "user_profile_update_errors". so it does not work without press "Edit" button in user edit page. Which should I use function for it?

access levels are deleted if the date entered is greater than today's date.

```
add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'crf_user_profile_update_errors', 10, 3 );

function crf_user_profile_update_errors($errors, $update, $user ) {
$current_date = date("Y-m-d");
$date_to_compare = $_POST['year_of_birth'];
if ( ! $update ) {
    return;
}
            //Bugünün Tarihi//            //Girilen Tarih//
if (strtotime($current_date > strtotime($date_to_compare)) ) {
    $user_levels = rua_get_user($user)->get_level_ids(false, false, true);
    foreach ($user_levels as $level) {
            rua_get_user($user)->remove_level($level);
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I know of to perform an action daily (or on another regular interval) is to schedule a cron event. A sustainable way to do that is to write a little plugin that schedules/clear_schedules the cron when activated/deactivated. Here's a plugin that you could use - I tested to ensure that it was installable and registered the cron event correctly. You will need to either place this in a file (such as custom_cron_event.php) and FTP it to your /plugins folder, or place it in a file and compress (ZIP) the file to upload it to your website through the /wp-admin interface.

Sadly, you can't rely on a function that fires when user profiles are updated to retrieve user data anymore, because no profiles are being updated. Instead you'll need to get the users your self and detect if a change is required.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Plugin
Plugin URI: 
Description: Adds function on cron
Author: 
Version: 1.0
*/

/*  
 * When this plugin is activated, schedule/clear_schedule cron
 */ 
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'activate_custom_cron');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactivate_custom_cron');

function activate_custom_cron(){
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'do_custom_cron_event');
}

function deactivate_custom_cron(){  
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('do_custom_cron_event');    
}

add_action( 'do_custom_cron_event', 'custom_cron_event' );

function custom_cron_event() {

/*
 * This is where your function goes
 */

     $current_date = date("Y-m-d");

     $users = get_users();
     foreach( $users as $user){

        $date_to_compare = get_user_meta($user->id, 'year_of_birth');

        if (strtotime($current_date) > strtotime($date_to_compare) ) {

            $user_levels = rua_get_user($user)->get_level_ids(false, false, true);

            foreach ($user_levels as $level) {
                rua_get_user($user)->remove_level($level);
            }
        }
    }
}   

?>
```

Comment: this code works with my function?

Comment: No- your function requires user profiles to fire. This feature is intended to replace your function and fire on a schedule (cron). I've included the action part of your function in the code. The only thing I can't know is if I'm getting "$date_to_compare" correctly. My original reply explains these issues.

Comment: $date_to_compare is entered date in user edit page

Comment: I edited date_to compare to get_the_author_meta( 'year_of_birth', $user->ID ) then when I press "Run" it worked but schedule does not work. DISABLE_WP_CRON must be true or false? I wrote 'everyminute' instead of 'daily' for the Test

Comment: Where did you press "Run"? You can install this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/amr-cron-manager/ and verify that the cron event is scheduled. "custom_cron_event" Should be listed as a scheduled cron if you've activated the file as a plugin correctly.

Comment: I installed this https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/ there is a button called "Run" and I pressed it. cron job does not work with it

Comment: Did you install the script I provided as a plugin? "You will need to either place this in a file (such as custom_cron_event.php) and FTP it to your /plugins folder, or place it in a file and compress (ZIP) the file to upload it to your website through the /wp-admin interface."

Comment: yes did not work again.

Comment: I don't know if there's an every minute interval, but you can set a custom interval: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/understanding-wp-cron-scheduling/

You could try running the code within "custom_cron_event()" manually by adding it as an action "add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_cron_event');" so that it fires ever page load. 

My bet is that it isn't performing the action you desire (and I can't get you much closer without knowing more about the website config).

Comment: I installed WP Crontrol plugin and it works now. thank you very much your help :)

Comment: Awesome! If you consider my answer correct, please indicate that it is the accepted answer! Best of luck on your WP endeavors!